# HTTP Outbound Gateway - Passing URI parameters

Tags: spring-integration

I need to invoke a REST API via Spring Integration's HTTP outbound gateway. How do I substitute the path variable with a value from payload. Payload has just one String value. The following code snippet is sending the place holder as such. Any help is appreciated.

```
@Bean
public MessageHandler   httpGateway(@Value("http://localhost:8080/api/test-resource/v1/{parameter1}/codes") URI uri) {
    HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler httpHandler = new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler(uri);
    httpHandler.setExpectedResponseType(Map.class);
    httpHandler.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
    Map<String, Expression> uriVariableExp = new HashMap();

    SpelExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

    uriVariableExp.put("parameter1", parser.parseExpression("payload.Message"));
    httpHandler.setUriVariableExpressions(uriVariableExp);
    return httpHandler;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let take a look what `@Value` is for first of all!

```
 * Annotation at the field or method/constructor parameter level
 * that indicates a default value expression for the affected argument.
 *
 * <p>Typically used for expression-driven dependency injection. Also supported
 * for dynamic resolution of handler method parameters, e.g. in Spring MVC.
 *
 * <p>A common use case is to assign default field values using
 * "#{systemProperties.myProp}" style expressions.
```

Looking to your sample there is nothing to resolve as a dependency injection value.

You can just use:

```
new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler("http://localhost:8080/api/test-resource/v1/{parameter1}/codes");
```

Although it doesn't matter in this case...

You code looks good, unless we don't know what your `payload` is.
That `payload.Message` expression looks odd. From big height it may mean like `MyClass.getMessage()`, but it can't invoke the getter because you use a property name as capitalized. If you really have there such a getter, so use it like `payload.message`. Otherwise, please, elaborate more. Some logs, StackTrace, the info about `payload` etc... It's fully unclear what is the problem.

Comment: thanks Artem. It is working fine now. I have moved the url to application.properties and updated the Expression as below                                    uriVariableExp.put("parameter1", parser.parseExpression("payload"));